# Search by date in Article Manager Administrator

Tags: joomla-4.x, search, article-manager, date

Is there a way to search by date in the Article Manager Administrator?

You can search using the text input, but it doesn't allow you to search for dates, only ID, AUTHOR, CONTENT, or a free text.

I need to search the articles at the article manager by their dates (created dates), example: I would like to get all the articles from 2021 and exclude all the rest.

I'm using Joomla 4.4.1

Answer (score 1):

Searching on dates is not a default functionality in Joomla 4.

The only search options that you have is to search for id:, author:, content:, or free text (which is searched for in the title, alias, and note fields). You can see that in the code https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/4.4-dev/administrator/components/com_content/src/Model/ArticlesModel.php line 448:

```
// Filter by search in title.
        $search = $this->getState('filter.search');

        if (!empty($search)) {
            if (stripos($search, 'id:') === 0) {
                $search = (int) substr($search, 3);
                $query->where($db->quoteName('a.id') . ' = :search')
                    ->bind(':search', $search, ParameterType::INTEGER);
            } elseif (stripos($search, 'author:') === 0) {
                $search = '%' . substr($search, 7) . '%';
                $query->where('(' . $db->quoteName('ua.name') . ' LIKE :search1 OR ' . $db->quoteName('ua.username') . ' LIKE :search2)')
                    ->bind([':search1', ':search2'], $search);
            } elseif (stripos($search, 'content:') === 0) {
                $search = '%' . substr($search, 8) . '%';
                $query->where('(' . $db->quoteName('a.introtext') . ' LIKE :search1 OR ' . $db->quoteName('a.fulltext') . ' LIKE :search2)')
                    ->bind([':search1', ':search2'], $search);
            } else {
                $search = '%' . str_replace(' ', '%', trim($search)) . '%';
                $query->where(
                    '(' . $db->quoteName('a.title') . ' LIKE :search1 OR ' . $db->quoteName('a.alias') . ' LIKE :search2'
                        . ' OR ' . $db->quoteName('a.note') . ' LIKE :search3)'
                )
                    ->bind([':search1', ':search2', ':search3'], $search);
            }
        }
```

A **workaround** is to **order** the articles on **date**. The ordering filter (not the column header) has options to choose to filter on "Created date" or "Modified date".

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sorting by date is ok, but the need to search for a date is different than a sort (obvisouly), let's say you have hundreds of dates, even with a sort you'll have to search for a given date. Maybe the solution is overriding the model and implementing the search by myself.